# Typecast from char to int in C++ - strange value

Tags: c++, casting

I cannot figure out why this result in undefined behavoiur or whatever its called?

```
 char ch[10];
 strcpy(ch, "street1-3");

 char ch2 = ch[6];

 cout << ch2 << endl;
 int n = (int) ch2;
 n = n * 12;
 cout << n << endl;
```

that is cout first prints out position 6 of street1-3 that is "1".
Then when I am trying to typecast this char to an int the value becomes not what its expected to be, that is 12, instead 588.

output in the consolewindow

```
 1
 588
```

What I am doing wrong in the typecasting and how is it solved?

Comment: Do you want to do `int n = int(ch2 - '0');`?

Comment: @MohitJain - perfect :-)

Answer (score 8):

The character `'1'` doesn't have the ascii value of `1`. So `(int)'1' != (int)1`.

If you look at an ASCII table, you'll see that `'1' == 49`, and coincidentally (or not...) `49*12 == 588`.

Answer (score 0):

`(int)ch2` tells the compiler to interpret the char value in `ch2` as an int. Since characters are stored by ascii value, `ch2` contains `49`, which is what the calculation uses.

Instead of `(int)ch2` you should instead use `int(ch2)`, which will perform the conversion you expect.

Oh, and you should always avoid c style casts in c++ where possible - c++ provides a number of safer casts that you should use instead (dynamic,static,etc).

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 different behaviour for the operator `<<` on stream with `char` and `int`. With `char`, you get the corresponding character, i.e. `"1"`, wich has a ascii value of `49`. So when you do `int n = (int)ch2`, n has a value of `49`, then `n * 12` is equal to `588` which is outputed as a value because `n` is a int.

Answer (score 0):

AS ch2 = 1 , which is of type 'char' , when it is type cast into 'int' , it takes ASKII value of 1 which is 49 and assigns it to 'n' . And 49 * 12 is 588 which is output of your program .